# why do the first and last ticks of my pgfplot graph have different width?

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I have noticed that when I choose the tick marks of my graph to be outside, the first and the last ticks are thinner. Anybody know how to fix that? Here is the code I used. Below is the screenshot of the graph produced.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{balance} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subeqnarray}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=sf,labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}


\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont}% used with mathpazo 

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={semithick,black}}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    only marks,
    %mark size=3pt,
    %legend image post style={mark options={scale=1.3,fill=white,line width=0.8pt}},
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.3)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label/.style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$\epsilon_n$} [{\myfont -}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    xtick={0,0.5,...,1},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    %minor x tick num=1,
    xtick align=outside,
    %xminorgrids=true,
    every y tick/.style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$\sigma_n$} [{\myfont MPa}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=150,
    ytick={0,50,...,150},
    ytick pos=left,
    %minor y tick num=1,
    ytick align=outside,
    %yminorgrids=true,  
]
    \addplot [sharp plot,red,very thick,mark=*,mark options={scale=2,blue,fill=white}]
    coordinates{
    (0.2,40)
    (0.4,70)
    (0.6,100)
    (0.8,130)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much JouleV for correcting my text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! This happens because 50% of the outer ticks gets clipped away. If you enlarge the limits a tiny bit, this effect disappears. So you may want to add

```
enable tick line clipping=false
```

to the options of your `axis`. Here is a complete MWE, in which I stripped away the packages that are not directly related.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}

\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont}% used with mathpazo 


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={semithick,black}}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enable tick line clipping=false,
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    only marks,
    %mark size=3pt,
    %legend image post style={mark options={scale=1.3,fill=white,line width=0.8pt}},
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.3)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    xtick align=outside,
    ytick align=outside,
    major x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label/.style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$\epsilon_n$} [{\myfont -}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=1,
    xtick={0,0.5,1},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    %minor x tick num=1,
    %xminorgrids=true,
    every y tick/.append style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$\sigma_n$} [{\myfont MPa}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=150,
    ytick={0,50,...,150},
    ytick pos=left,
    %minor y tick num=1,
    %yminorgrids=true,  
]
    \addplot [sharp plot,red,very thick,mark=*,mark options={scale=2,blue,fill=white}]
    coordinates{
    (0.2,40)
    (0.4,70)
    (0.6,100)
    (0.8,130)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use, say, `enlargelimits={abs=0.4pt}`.

Comment: That's a nice trick but the graph doesn't look professional. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Well, it is for a paper I am about to submit in the Journal of Polymer Physics. The journal doesn't of course require this but I personally like when axis starts and ends with labeled ticks.

Comment: @Gagik I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: That is fantastic. Thank you so much marmot!

Comment: I would love to but I am not quite sure what mark you mean?

Comment: By the way, it works!